# How do I make Stack Overflow sort shown answers by relevance?

Tags: support

I don't remember changing any setting, but all of a sudden Stack Overflow answers start showing with irrelevant ordering:

An accepted answer can appear somewhere in the middle of other answers.

100+ votes answers can be under 0 votes.

How can I set this to the good old setting of the following?

1. Accepted answer
2. By votes.